# Display an icon on PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I am beginner in python and make a simple script to display a main window with an icon, but the icon didn't appear and there was not an error message too. I use Linux 16.04, PyQt4, python 2.7 and placed the logo.png and the script on Desktop. How to make the icon appear? Any help please. This is the .pyw script I use.

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("tricoba")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))
        self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try typing full path to "logo.png" ;

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle("tricoba")
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("home/user/desktop/logo.png")) #This line
    self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**This works for me in Ubuntu 14.10.**

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I did as you said, but it's still the same as before. The icon appear on taskbar but not on the main window of GUI's application.